# excel formula, detect building number in address

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column with addresses. I need a formula in excel to detect whether this data has a building number in the address line 1. Please see below sample data. I am trying to detect if this is a good address format or not in excel. This will help with my analysis. For example, H street below does not have a building number but 104 Washington Dr does have a building number. How can I build a formula to do this? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Could street names include numbers, eg: `57th Street`. In other words, what would be the "pattern" to tell wheather or not building numbers are included?

Comment: .. or Baker Street  Apt. 221

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2;"*"&{"1";"2";"3";"4";"5";"6";"7";"8";"9";"0"} & "*"))>0;"Yes";"No")
```

[image]

This is how it works:

1. `COUNTIF(A2;"*"&{"1";"2";"3";"4";"5";"6";"7";"8";"9";"0"} & "*")` will return an array of 0 and 1 if any number is present at any part of the string (we use wildcards * before and after)
2. We sum up the array from step 1 with `SUMPRODUCT`.
3. If the final sum is 0, it means NO, otherway means YES, because at least one number is present.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use something like this:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(VALUE(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IFERROR(MID(B6,ROW(INDIRECT("1:100")),1)+0,"")))))
```

This will return a boolean indicating that the string has numbers in it.

More explanation [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/strip-non-numeric-characters)